# Backup database command produces two different sizes of backup

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two database query which takes backup of my database.
First query produces backup of size ~307MB

```
declare @path varchar(max)
set @path=(select 'D:\Backup\ABC_'+ convert(varchar(500),GetDate(),112) + '.bak')
BACKUP DATABASE [ABC] TO  DISK = @path 
--WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'ABC-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

Below query produces backup of size ~1.8GB

```
BACKUP DATABASE [ABC] TO  DISK = N'D:\Backup\ABC.bak' 
--WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'ABC-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10  GO
```

Any idea why these two almost identical statements of backup producing two different size backup files.

Comment: I just made a quick test with the two statements and I have identical results for the 2 backups. Are you sure you are not missing anything meanwhile? Are you the only one working on the DB when  running the two statements?

Comment: Someone added a ton of data to your database after the first backup but before the second?  I ran your scripts on my test system with a  500 MB database and both backups were exactly 129 MB.

Comment: I am the only one using this ABC Database now. When I run these queries 3-4 times after posting my question here, I started getting equal sizes of database back up. Is not it weird?

Comment: try adding the INIT option to make sure you're comparing apples to apples. Overwrite vs Append.

Comment: Also `set @path=(select 'D:\Backup\ABC_'+ convert(varchar(500),GetDate(),112) + '.bak')` is the same as set `@path='D:\Backup\ABC_' + convert(varchar(500),GetDate(),112) + '.bak'`